# Mysql self join produces duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p1.last_name, p1.first_name, p1.city, p1.state
FROM president AS p1 INNER JOIN president AS p2
ON p1.city = p2.city AND p1.state = p2.state
WHERE (p1.last_name <> p2.last_name OR p1.first_name <> p2.first_name)
ORDER BY state, city, last_name;
```

As the script says it's supposed to display different values of names that have the same cities and state.
Then the same first names OR last names from p1 and p2 will be ignored.

however i am getting this on the output.

```
last_name  first_name    City         State
--------------------------------------------
'Adams', 'John Quincy', 'Braintree', 'MA'
'Adams', 'John',        'Braintree', 'MA'
'Obama', 'Barack',      'New York', 'NY'
'Roosevelt', 'Theodore', 'New York', 'NY'
'Bush', 'George',        'Westmoreland', 'VA'
'Bush', 'George',        'Westmoreland', 'VA'
'Monroe', 'James',      'Westmoreland', 'VA'
'Monroe', 'James',      'Westmoreland', 'VA'
'Washington', 'George', 'Westmoreland', 'VA'
'Washington', 'George', 'Westmoreland', 'VA'
```

It displays two values of George Bush, James Monroe and George Washington. I checked my database and i am positive that there are no other duplicate values of these names.

Comment: Come on. Your table is small enough that you can just post the whole thing, right?

Comment: Of course it is doing that. Your query doesn't do what you describe. From the join yuo get three guys from Westmoreland, VA. For Bush it finds two records with a different name (Monroe and Washington), so it displays Bush twice. Same for the other two. If you find 4 presidents from the same state, they will show up three times each.

Comment: Ok thanks i get now how self-join works

Answer (score -2, accepted):

why dont you group the records?

```
SELECT p1.last_name, p1.first_name, p1.city, p1.state
FROM president AS p1 INNER JOIN president AS p2
ON p1.city = p2.city AND p1.state = p2.state
WHERE (p1.last_name <> p2.last_name OR p1.first_name <> p2.first_name)
GROUP BY p1.last_name, p1.first_name, p1.city, p1.state
ORDER BY state, city, last_name
```

Comment: A simple DISTINCT would be preferable in this case

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is a simple DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.last_name, p1.first_name, p1.city, p1.state
 FROM president AS p1 INNER JOIN president AS p2
   ON p1.city = p2.city AND p1.state = p2.state
WHERE (p1.last_name <> p2.last_name OR p1.first_name <> p2.first_name)
ORDER BY state, city, last_name;
```

(A group by on all selected fields produces the same result but is less readable and less maintainable.)

Answer (score 0):

While comparing the values of first and last name, try to use TRIM in the query

```
SELECT p1.last_name, p1.first_name, p1.city, p1.state
FROM president AS p1 INNER JOIN president AS p2
ON p1.city = p2.city AND p1.state = p2.state
WHERE (TRIM(p1.last_name) <> TRIM(p2.last_name) OR TRIM(p1.first_name) <> TRIM(p2.first_name))
ORDER BY state, city, last_name;
```